# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl

Tags: libraries, gcc

After running the following command:

`g++ lex.yy.c -lfl`

I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl`

How can I solve it?

Comment: What distribution/OS are you using?  How did you install flex (if that's what you're using)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`lex.yy.c` is the default output file name for [`lex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29), the lexical analyzer preprocessor for C (and C++). The [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ld_%28Unix%29) (`ld`) is looking for a file called `libfl.so` (if linking dynamically; it would be `libfl.a` if linking statically). This is the runtime library required by lexers generated by [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser), a lex implementation.

If you generated `lex.yy.c` yourself with `flex`, check that Flex is installed correctly. In addition to having the `flex` executable in your path, you need to have `libfl.so` and `libfl.a` (and `libfl_pic.a` if it exists) in your library search path (typically `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`, depending on whether Flex came from a system package or not). If you have Flex in a non-standard location, specify the library search path with `-L`:

```
~/software/flex/bin/flex mylexer.l
g++ lex.yy.c -L ~/software/flex/lib -lfl
```

Comment: installing flex-static package solved the problem

Comment: Mint 19.1, installing flex-old helps.

Answer (score 6):

Installing the `flex-devel.x86_64` package in my SciOs distro worked for me.